# Spring boot container runs locally but not on EC2

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, amazon-ec2

I have a spring boot microservice in a docker container. The container runs locally just fine but it doesn't on EC2. My local Java version is 12. My local docker version is 18.06.1-ce, same as the EC2 instance docker version.

The dockerfile is as follows

```
FROM openjdk:12-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
COPY target/my-api-0.0.1.jar /app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

when I try to run this container on EC2 I get the error:

```
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /app.jar
```

EC2's Java version is 1.7.0_231. But I imagine that since I'm using Java 12 in my docker container the container would execute the jar inside it in a java 12 environment.

I don't know why I'm still getting the "invalid or corrupt jar" error.

I have done `mvn clean` and `mvn package` before building the docker container locally.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated to the problem but why don't you use a JRE container? JDK should not be required to run the application in you case.

Comment: An idea related to the problem: In case you have updated the container and pushed it multiple times to the registry with the same version/tag, you have to run `docker pull` again on the EC2 instance. Otherwise it will use the outdated version.

Comment: great ideas! you're right i should use JRE duh! will let you know if this works, thanks.

Comment: @alsdkjasdlkja `docker pull` is all i needed! it works now thanks :) can you put your comment as an answer so I can give you the recognition for solving this?

Comment: is there a way you can run docker image inspect in EC2 instance and compare? the sha value with local image.